# Overriding the default stop intent in Google Assistant

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

i'm creating an Google Assistant action and
my problem is i just want to override the Default stop intent with my own sentences 
so that when the user says Stop or Cancel then i would like to say something like "Thanks for using the app"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

[This feature](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/conversation-exits) has been available for some time, so the below answer is obsolete.

**Previous Answer**

Google has indicated that this is a bug, but doesn't seem to be high on their priority list to fix. In the meantime, make sure you add other "ending" phrases such as "goodbye", "thank you", "I'm done", and other phrases that make sense for your Action.

Answer (score 0):

In the new "Actions Console" you can do it this way:

1. Go to your intents and click on the Global intent called "Stop"
2. On the intent page click the blue button that says "Edit Global Intent Handling"
3. There you can add a prompt with its variants once that someone says "Stop" or anything similiar to get out of your action.